# ¿Cómo iterar en las celdas de una columna de una hoja de cálculo para obtener las preguntas de un formulario de Google?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, scraping, google-forms

Tengo una [hoja de cálculo de Google con enlaces a cuestionarios](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLqEFRaHPYxpJKU05VXt3HUCQ2OQUAg8FfWlyFbvaXc/edit?usp=sharing). Quería saber cómo obtener las preguntas de cada uno de los cuestionarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que tengo que hacer: en el mejor de los casos, usar el editor del guión e iterar en las líneas, y en el peor, hacer webscrapping.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function appendString() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
      await page.goto(currentValue);

      const pollFrame = page.frames().find() // aqui no se como hacer a causa de lo que sigue ...

    }
  }
}
```

Sin mencionar el botón en el que tengo que hacer clic, la selección se ve así:

```
<div class="freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle exportItemTitle freebirdCustomFont" id="i1" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i.desc.310938276">How often did you fly before the Covid-19 epidemic? </div>
```

Pero las identificaciones no siguen un orden numérico lógico, así que no sé cómo extraerlas automáticamente.

Entonces no sé cómo hacerlo. Me pregunto si es más simple porque son productos del mismo proveedor.

Comment: Publicación cruzada en [so] https://stackoverflow.com/q/61955306/1595451

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo había mencionado en inglés en mi respuesta a [la publicación cruzada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61955306/1595451) de esta pregunta en SO, pero lo menciono ahora en español (no es una traducción de mi respuesta en inglés)

1. `require` no es un soportado por Google Apps Script pues no es un función de JavaScript estándar.
2. `await` tampoco es soportado por Google Apps Script pues aunque ahora es posible usar el Chrome V8 como runtime Google Apps Script no soporta métodos asíncronos.
3. No es recomendable leer una celda a la vez usando `getValue()` ya que este método es lento. En el documento de mejores prácticas de Google Apps Script se recomienda leer todos los valores de cada hoja usando métodos como `getValues()`  y luego iterar sobre la matriz devuelta por estos métodos.
4. Ya te he dejado varias observaciones sobre los formularios de Google en tu pregunta sobre Selenium -> [¿Cómo iterar en los enlaces a los formularios de Google en las celdas de una columna de la hoja de cálculo para obtener sus preguntas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/358244/65)