# ¿Cómo obtener los textos de los elementos que se correspondían con find_element_by_class_name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-forms

Estoy tratando de obtener las preguntas relacionadas de [este cuestionario](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzocEm6IEDKVzVGOlg8ijysWZyAvQur0NheJb_I_xozgKusA/viewform)

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
location = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLqEFRaHPYxpJKU05VXt3HUCQ2OQUAg8FfWlyFbvaXc/edit?usp=sharing"
location = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzocEm6IEDKVzVGOlg8ijysWZyAvQur0NheJb_I_xozgKusA/viewform?usp=sf_link"

class_name = "freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle.exportItemTitle.freebirdCustomFont"
driver.get(location)
time.sleep(1.5)


questions = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
print(questions.text)
```

Pero yo obtengo solo el primero:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>python3 questions_scraper.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55562/devtools/browser/d30bdba2-39f2-4ec9-8aa9-e61439b474b5
[38340:34544:0527/173840.814:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
How often did you fly before the Covid-19 epidemic?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar `find_elements_by_class_name` y no `find_element_by_class_name` e iterar sobre la lista, no obstante, si quieres obtener todas las preguntas deberás hacer click en el botón <kbd>Siguiente</kbd> y volver a buscar la clase.

Si además quieres la respuestas se complica un poco:

- Buscamos todos los contenedores con cada pregunta y sus respuestas.
- Por cada contenedor:

  - Obtenemos la pregunta
  - Obtenemos las respuestas
- Click en el botón <kbd>Siguiente</kbd>

Lo anterior lo repetimos mientras no se termine el formulario.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


location = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzocEm6IEDKVzVGOlg8ijysWZyAvQur0NheJb_I_xozgKusA/viewform?usp=sf_link"

data = {}

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(location)

title = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
    "freebirdFormviewerViewHeaderTitleRow"
    ).text
data[title] = {}

while True:
    containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        "freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer"
        )
    btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".appsMaterialWizButtonEl")
    if not btns:
        break
    for container in containers:
        try:
            question = container.find_element_by_class_name(
                "freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle"
                )
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        responses = container.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText"
            )
        data[title][question.text] = [response.text for response in responses]
    btns[-1].click()
driver.quit()

print(data)
```

El resultado es un diccionario con todas las preguntas y sus respuestas posibles:

```
{
    "Air Travel": {
        "How often did you fly before the Covid-19 epidemic?": [
            "Once per year",
            "Between two and five times per year",
            "More than five times per year"
        ],
        "What did you dislike the most about Pre-Covid 19 air travel?": [
            "Long waits at security",
            "Layovers",
            "Entertainment on flight",
            "Cramped seating on the flight",
            "Otro:"
        ],
        "Did you feel safe flying before the Covid-19 pandemic?": [
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ],
        "How long will you wait before flying again, after Covid-19?": [
            "30 Days",
            "30 - 90 Days",
            "90 - 180 Days",
            "More than 180 Days"
        ],
        "Will you fly for pleasure or only when absolutely necessary?": [
            "Pleasure",
            "Only When Absolutely Necessary"
        ],
        "Would a flight with a guaranteed empty seat between you and the person sitting next to you make you more comfortable?": [
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ],
        "What can we do to make you feel as safe as possible while flying with us?": [],
        "Will you be more interested in the cheapest flight or the airline that offers the highest level of protection from disease?": [
            "Cheapest Flight",
            "Level of Protection From Disease",
            "Mix of Both"
        ],
        "Would you take advantage of a new class of seating that offered improved social distancing during the flight as well as complimentary personal protection equipment?": [
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ],
        "Which of these options would you like to see the most of your next flight?": [
            "The latest movies",
            "Free hand sanitizer and wipes",
            "Free meal for longer flight or free drinks on shorter ones",
            "Scheduled check-in time so you can avoid waiting in a large crowd",
            "Otro:"
        ]
    }
}
```